# Python - multiprocessing - API query

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am preparing code for querying some endpoints. Code is ok, works quite good but it takes too much time. I would like to use Python `multiprocessing` module to speed up the process. My main target is to put 12 API queries to be processed in parallel. Once jobs are processed I would like to fetch the result and put them into the list of dictionaries, one response as one dictionary in the list. API response is in `json` format. I am new to Python and don't have experience in such kind of cases.
Code I want to run in parallel below.

```
def api_query_process(cloud_type, api_name, cloud_account, resource_type):

    url = "xxx"
    payload = {
        "limit": 0,
        "query": f'config from cloud.resource where cloud.type = \'{cloud_type}\' AND api.name = \'{api_name}\' AND '
                 f'cloud.account = \'{cloud_account}\'',
        "timeRange": {
            "relativeTimeType": "BACKWARD",
            "type": "relative",
            "value": {
                "amount": 0,
                "unit": "minute"
            }
        },
        "withResourceJson": True
    }

    headers = {
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "x-redlock-auth": api_token_input
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload, headers=headers)

    result = response.json()
    resource_count = len(result["data"]["items"])

    if resource_count:
        dictionary = dictionary_create(cloud_type, cloud_account, resource_type, resource_count)
        property_list_summary.append(dictionary)
    else:
        dictionary = dictionary_create(cloud_type, cloud_account, resource_type, 0)
        property_list_summary.append(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem and I think you should think about idempotency. What would happen if you hit the end-point consecutively. You can use multiprocessing with or without lock.

**Without Lock:**

```py
import multiprocessing

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=12) as pool:
    jobs = []
    for _ in range(12):
        jobs.append(pool.apply_async(api_query_process(*args))
    for job in jobs:
        job.wait()
```

**With Lock:**

```py
import multiprocessing

multiprocessing_lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

def locked_api_query_process(cloud_type, api_name, cloud_account, resource_type):
    with multiprocessing_lock:
        api_query_process(cloud_type, api_name, cloud_account, resource_type)

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=12) as pool:
    jobs = []
    for _ in range(12):
        jobs.append(pool.apply_async(locked_api_query_process(*args)))
    for job in jobs:
        job.wait()
```

Can't really do an End-2-End test but hopefully this general setup helps you get it up and running.

Comment: ok, but what should be put under this part --> `api_query_process(*args)`. Function name like `api_query_process`? How to put all arguments here. I am trying to test on a simple code, and getting error message.

Comment: This is just your original defined function presented in the question. So the args are just `api_query_process(cloud_type, api_name, cloud_account, resource_type)`

Comment: thx, looks good, but how to fetch data from the `jobs[]` array, and then put them into the dictionary or list? I read about shared variable, but I am not sure how to use it in the case.

Answer (score 0):

Since a HTTP request is an I/O Bound operation, you do not need multiprocessing. You can use threads to get a better performance. Something like the following would help.

- `MAX_WORKERS` would say how many requests you want to send in
  parallel
- `API_INPUTS` are all the requests you want to make

Untested code sample:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import requests


API_TOKEN = "xyzz"
MAX_WORKERS = 4
API_INPUTS = (
    ("cloud_type_one", "api_name_one", "cloud_account_one", "resource_type_one"),
    ("cloud_type_two", "api_name_two", "cloud_account_two", "resource_type_two"),
    ("cloud_type_three", "api_name_three", "cloud_account_three", "resource_type_three"),
)


def make_api_query(api_token_input, cloud_type, api_name, cloud_account):
    url = "xxx"
    payload = {
        "limit": 0,
        "query": f'config from cloud.resource where cloud.type = \'{cloud_type}\' AND api.name = \'{api_name}\' AND '
                 f'cloud.account = \'{cloud_account}\'',
        "timeRange": {
            "relativeTimeType": "BACKWARD",
            "type": "relative",
            "value": {
                "amount": 0,
                "unit": "minute"
            }
        },
        "withResourceJson": True
    }
    headers = {
        "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        "x-redlock-auth": api_token_input
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", url, json=payload, headers=headers)
    return response.json()


def main():
    futures = []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS) as pool:
        for (cloud_type, api_name, cloud_account, resource_type) in API_INPUTS:
            futures.append(
                pool.submit(make_api_query, API_TOKEN, cloud_type, api_name, cloud_account)
            )

    property_list_summary = []

    for future, api_input in zip(futures, API_INPUTS):
        api_response = future.result()
        cloud_type, api_name, cloud_account, resource_type = api_input

        resource_count = len(api_response["data"]["items"])
        dictionary = dictionary_create(cloud_type, cloud_account, resource_type, resource_count)
        property_list_summary.append(dictionary)
```

Comment: In the second function I am getting an error while executing this line `api_response = future.result()`.  There is something wrong with the `api_response = future.result()`. Under `futures` I can see jobs: `[<Future at 0x2af6ffcf490 state=finished raised JSONDecodeError>, <Future at 0x2af70048130 state=finished raised JSONDecodeError>,`....but there is a message `JSONDecodeError`

Comment: Unfortunately this code does not work, I tested exact the same code as you pasted and getting an error. :(

Comment: @tester81 as per the error you get (`JSONDecodeError`), it means the API is not returning a valid JSON response. The code provided is meant as a starting point for your to get started :) 

Please modify it as per your API requirements

Comment: I am not sure how this code should look like, can you give me some more details? As `API_INPUTS` I am using list of dictionaries, like `API_INPUTS = [{"cloud_type": "aws", "api_name": "aaa", "cloud_account": "bbb", "resource_type": "EC2 Images"},......]`. Function `make_api_query` should give good results, I tested it many times. Is that FOR loop looks ok for You? --> `for (cloud_type, api_name, cloud_account, resource_type) in API_INPUTS:`. Under `futures` I am getting list like this --> `[<Future at 0x14e4e51fb20 state=finished returned dict>, <Future at 0x14e4e78c970 state=finished ...`

Answer (score 0):

I think using async functions would help a lot in speeding this up.
Your code is blocking while it waits for a response from the external API. So using more processes or threads is overkill. You dont need more resources on your end. Instead you should just make your code execute the next request instead of idling until the response arrives. This can be done using coroutines.
You could use [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) instead of requests, collect the individual tasks and execute them in an event loop.

Here is a small example code to run get requests, and collect the json bodies from the responses. Should be easy to adapt to your use case

```py
from aiohttp import ClientSession
import asyncio

RESULTS = dict()

async def get_url(url, session):
    
    async with session.get(url) as response:

        print("Status:", response.status)
        print("Content-type:", response.headers['content-type'])

        result = await response.json()

    RESULTS[url] = result


async def get_all_urls(urls):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [get_url(url, session) for url in urls]
   
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    urls = [
        "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration",
        "https://www.facebook.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/"
    ]

    asyncio.run(get_all_urls(urls=urls))

    print(RESULTS.keys())
```